# Debug crashing/reboot when in safe mode Samsung Galaxy S6

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have a samsung galaxy s6 (SM-G920F) running marshmallow 6.0.1 that has been rebooting frequently even when in safe mode. If the device is plugged into a USB cable it seems to freeze when trying to boot after the crash

Have tried a cache partition wipe and clearing all app cache (although downloaded apps won't be launched in safemode anyway)

Is there any way to debug what's causing the phone to crash/reboot?

Comment: If you have it plugged-in via USB anyway, you could [capture the logs](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info).